# do... while loop in original 1978 awk?

Tags: awk

Does the do... while loop work in the original awk? Or has it been introduced in later implementations (nawk, gawk, ...)? Can nawk be considered present on all Unix platforms today?

Greets, Oliver

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Nope, actually I'm learning awk and I wanted to write down a small tutorial for myself but most of the tutorials i found on the web focus on [gmn]awk without mentioning it...

Answer (score 1):

The do while loop is documented in Solaris (o)awk so likely predates the newer [gn]awk standard.

I believe all current Unix/Unix like platforms provide either gawk, nawk or a compliant awk.

Answer (score 1):

Per page 49 of *The AWK Programming Language* book by Aho, Weinberger, and Kernighan (the AWK), it should.

I've not seen a modern UNIX variant that didn't provide nawk, however.

Answer (score 1):

It should be there. If you want to use ancient awk, run gawk with the `--traditional` option.

Answer (score 1):

According to `info gawk` in Appendix A, Section 1 "Major Changes Between V7 and SVR3.1":

> The `awk' language evolved considerably between the release of Version
>   7 Unix (1978) and the new version that was first made generally
>   available in System V Release 3.1 (1987).  This minor node summarizes
>   the changes, with cross-references to further details:
>
> - The `do'-'while' statement